# git cherry-pick: manually accept "our" or "their" hunks in conflicted files

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I'm currently cherry-picking a number of commits into another (release) branch. I know about the `--strategy-option theirs` when cherry-picking, but I'm afraid that this option isn't suitable for every commit I'm picking.

I'd prefer running with the default strategy generating conflicts, then manually resolve those for each file.

However, there are some files where I'd like to batch-accept all `ours` or `their` hunks, which is getting cumbersome doing it by hand.
Is there a way to just accept all `ours` or `their` hunks in a conflicted file?

Note: `git checkout --ours/--theirs` seems unsuitable for cherry-picking as it checks out the whole file from the given branch. I only want to accept conflicting hunks from either version.

Comment: I was just thinking that `git checkout -m --theirs` would be a good fit, but unfortunately that combination isn't supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a really convenient way to do this, but you can build one from the tools Git provides.  The main tool required is this `git merge-file`, which performs a three-way merge on a single trio of file-versions, i.e., base + ours + theirs.  It accepts `--ours` and `--theirs` options to resolve conflicts the same way that `-X ours` and `-X theirs` does for an overall merge, i.e., it doesn't just take our *file* or their *file*, it only takes ours or theirs at conflict-points.

That's all great, but, where you do get the three versions?  Git has stopped with a merge conflict on, say, `main.py`.  In your work-tree, `main.py` contains the mess that Git left behind, with the `<<<<<<< ... >>>>>>>` markers around the conflicted lines.  But `git merge-file` needs three un-marked-up input files, for the merge base version, the "ours" version, and the "theirs" version.  But those three files are in the *index!*  If file *F* had a conflict, there is a `:1:F` with the merge base version, `:2:F` with ours, and `:3:F` with theirs.

To get them, you can either use `git show` or `git checkout-index`.  The latter is actually the right tool: `git mergetool` uses `git checkout-index`, with this little shell function:

```
checkout_staged_file () {
        tmpfile=$(expr \
                "$(git checkout-index --temp --stage="$1" "$2" 2>/dev/null)" \
                : '\([^ ]*\)    ')

        if test $? -eq 0 && test -n "$tmpfile"
        then
                mv -- "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)$tmpfile" "$3"
        else
                >"$3"
        fi
}
```

Invoked as `checkout_staged_file 1 main.py main.py.base`, for instance, it extracts the stage-1 (merge base) copy of `main.py` to `main.py.base`.  Repeat with 2 and 3, and suitable variants on the third argument, to get all three files out.  Then, run `git merge-file` on the three files in the way described in [the `git merge-file` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file).

(See [the `git mergetool` source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-mergetool.sh) for more.  It's just a big shell script, so it's pretty easy to read and modify for your own purposes.)

Comment: That sounds great, thanks! I'll try it tomorrow. Still sounds like a missing piece in the toolchain tough.

Comment: @resi: it really is—there should be a `git remerge <file>` that accepts ours/theirs/union arguments, and otherwise is like doing all of the fiddling described above and then running `git merge-file`. (It might even include the `git checkout -m` action that uses the REUC record in the index to "unresolve" a previously resolved file.)

Comment: I just tested it out, works like a charm. Thanks @torek!

Comment: It turns out this can be easily configured as custom `git mergetool`, see https://gist.github.com/diresi/a9f0bd3f68e76d0576be4a709ee421ba

Comment: just so you know, I just remembered this post+answer and I'm happy it's all still working and useful. thx!